# BackUp SQL tablas especificas programable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017, mssql

Buenas tardes compañeros, quiero saber si existe la posibilidad de programar un JOB o crear un procedimiento almacenado que me permita generar un respaldo de la estructura y los datos de unas tablas en especificas(tal cual como se puede hacer por task->Generate Scripts) pero que se realice automático cada cierto tiempo, ejemplo semanalmente. Ya genere un JOB para el backup de la base de datos general para cada mes, pero no encuentro la manera de que se genere el script para solo ciertas tablas sin tener que ejecutarlo manualmente.

Gracias de antemano y adjunto el script para el backup completo que integre.

```
USE base_de_Datos/*Seleccionar BD*/
GO
DECLARE @fecha varchar(10),@archivo varchar(50); /*Declaracion de variables para fecha y nombre del archivo*/
SET @fecha = convert(varchar, getdate(), 105)/*Asignando datos a la variable fecha*/
SET @archivo = 'D:\Backup SQL\Duplicado'+@fecha+'.bak'/*Asignando datos a la variable del archivo*/

BACKUP DATABASE [base_de_Datos]/*Orden para generar el backup*/
TO  DISK = @archivo /*Seleccion de ubicacion del backup*/
WITH CHECKSUM,
NAME = 'base_de_Datos';
GO
```

Comment: A diferencia del Backup, la opción de generar scripts es una que provee el SQL Server Management Studio, y no el motor como tal. Por tanto, no hay una instrucción que puedas darle al motor para que lo haga. Me pregunto ¿por qué estás pensando en esta opción como una solución y no en tener un backup integral de la DB?

Comment: Generar un respaldo mensual es simplemente algo absurdo. Si algo pasa, puedes perder más de 30 días de trabajo. Peor aún es el hecho de respaldar solo ciertas tablas. Si lo necesitas para enviarlo a otra base de datos, hay diferentes soluciones que se pueden usar. Pero si es por seguridad de los datos, todo el concepto está mal.

Comment: Gracias @jachguate 
Realmente fue una solicitud que me realizo un superior, ya que la base de datos se usa solo en algunas ocasiones para ingresar registros no es de uso transaccional y el espacio en memoria no es muy amplio para las copias de seguridad en el área; el superior prefiere tener en el equipo de él copias de solo dos tablas, pero por mi parte si tengo aparte un espacio para los backup integrales, que se realizan mensual por que no es algo que se trabaje al diario, como nota adicional cree un pequeño instructivo para que él u otro usuario pueda hacer la copia de las tablas.